# Regex to admit space on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a form field , i need this fields admitts only letters and spaces but if I write an space in the form the field is not validated,what is the regex which allows to write blank spaces??

```
function isCharacter(element, message){
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]\s+$/;
    if(element.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `\s*` instead of `\s+` both side of `[...]`. `\s+` means one or more space in the end of the string. or better write it inside the `[...]` otherwise it will accept only single character along with one or more spaces

Comment: Your `+` quantifier only affects the `\s`, not the `[a-zA-Z]`. So your pattern matches a character followed by any number of whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the first character to be aphabet, and then alphabet or spaces as

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

This ensures that the input filed will not contains spaces alone

```
"asdf asdf".match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/)
=> True

"   ".match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/)
=> False
```

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is with your regex, you have to put the `\s` **inside the** `[]` to achieve it.

```
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
```

**[Here's a DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zQ1lS1/1)**.

Answer (score 0):

**Can use**  `html5 pattern` for easily handle

```html
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]+$" />
<input type="submit" value="ok" name="ok" />
```

Comment: That doesn't really explain what's wrong about the expression now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var idLetters = ["a", "b", "m"]; 

var counter = 0;
var counter1 = 0;
var errors = "";

var numberonly = id.slice(0,-1);
var lettersonly = id.slice(-1);
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.